# How to get only the local data when using a distributed map in hazelcast?

Tags: hazelcast

I am studying Hazelcast for a side project I have. I am particularly interested in the cluster management and partition capabilities of Hazelcast.

In this project I have nodes that share a map and they will all get a request with a number. I want each of these nodes to look on their local partition and return the entries of the map that have the given number as value.

This is an example implementation. What I am actually trying to achieve is understand how I can use Hazelcast to share load: I am interested in the partition re-balancing and cluster management that hazelcast offers, but I want to avoid the fact that a `get()` in a distributed map will cause a `get()` in all cluster.

Putting it in another way: I want to be able to use hazelcast to distribute state, but I want nodes to operate in the local state only.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can see the local keys via [IMap#localKeySet](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/0aebca1a41be59415f11babaf918224338997d1e/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/map/IMap.java#L2454). It returns the locally owned immutable set of keys.
2. You can also track the entries of local map via [IMap#addLocalEntryListener](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/0aebca1a41be59415f11babaf918224338997d1e/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/map/IMap.java#L2064). Say your cluster has member1 and member2. On member2 you added a local listener. Then, from member1 you call `map.put(key2, value2)`. If key2 is owned by member2 then the local listener will be notified for the add/update event.
3. Finally, you can track local map statistics via [IMap#getLocalMapStats](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/0aebca1a41be59415f11babaf918224338997d1e/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/map/IMap.java#L2557), in case they help.

Comment: Hi @ozcan, thanks for your reply. number 1 is my current approach. If I do `get(keyThatExistsLocally)`, is this going to be distributed through all the node?

Comment: `map.get(key)` always reads the value from the actual owner of the key, unless backup reads are not enabled explicitly. So, by the time you make a get call, if the key is still owned by this node, it won't ask any other node for the key since it is the owner and contains the value.